# Goals added to compile phase are not running in war package

Tags: java, maven-2, war, pom.xml

I am trying to run some goals as part of compile phase in war packaging but they are not working.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>sample-test</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scannotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <echo message ="hello"/>
                    </target>
                        <target name="get markdown.mustache">
                        <echo message="hello ant, from Maven!"/>
                        <get dest=".">
                            <url url="https://raw.github.com/kongchen/api-doc-template/master/v1.1/markdown.mustache"/>
                        </get>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/web.xml</packagingExcludes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

When I am running `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean compile` then task configured in `maven-antrun-plugin` are not running but when I am running `mvn antrun:run` then tasks are running.

**What am I doing wrong and How can it be corrected?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the plugins under `<pluginManagement>` which means you are defining the plugins for any pom which inherits from this pom (making this pom the parent).

You would need to have `<plugins>` defined directly under `<build>` if you want to use the plugins for this pom directly.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement/>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
        .....
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
        .....
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks dmahapatro!! I have wasted my half day on this. :):)

Comment: @ritesh Don't worry you will gain that half day when you come across this scenario again. :-)